# Boost::Lambda method deduction error MSVC9.0

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, boost, lambda

I have following code to merge two std::maps.

```
template <typename key, typename value>
  void merge_maps(std::map<key, value>& one, const std::map<key, value>& another,
    boost::function2<value, value, value> aggregate)
  {
    // MERGING. aggregate is called if key exists in both maps
  }
```

I have some struct like this.

```
  struct foo {
    int bar;
    foo operator+(const foo& other) const;
  };
```

I tries to merge two `std::map<std::wstring, foo> one, another` using `foo::operator+` which I passed using `boost::lambda`, but get compilation error.

```
  merge_maps(one, another, _1+_2); // MSCV9.0 cannot deduce template argument for lambda there
```

Help me please. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use `boost::function` to *store* any kind of callable. Use a simple template parameter `typename F` and as a function parameter `F f` if you only want to have a callback from inside the function.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I'll keep it on mind. But my problem was silly simple. It was needed just to specify lambda return type:  merge_maps(one, another, ret<foo>(_1+_2));

Comment: Just post that as an answer! :) Self-answering your question is encouraged if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It was needed to specify lambda return type. MSVC instantiates template without any troubles.

```
merge_maps(one, another, ret<foo>(_1+_2));
```